# Trouble ending a multi if statement to catch all

Tags: python

I am currently attempting to write my first program/app in Python by creating a tool for my partner to use when we play a card game.  I have just started to pick up learning to program seriously, so it maybe a rookie mistake I have missed, but I can't seem to catch "anything else" via input to divert the user a response.

Here is my code:

```
def counting_up ():
round_total = 0
while True :
    global game_level
    cards = input("Enter Card: \n")
    if cards.upper() == "A" or cards == "2" :
        round_total += 20
    if cards == "3" :
        round_total += 3
    if cards == "4":
        round_total += 4
    if cards == "5" :
        round_total += 5
    if cards == "6" : 
        round_total += 6
    if cards == "7" :
        round_total += 7
    if cards == "8" :
        round_total += 8
    if cards == "9" :
        round_total += 9
    if cards == "10" or cards.upper() == "J" or cards.upper() == "Q" or cards.upper() == "K" :
        round_total += 10
    if cards == "0" : 
        game_level += 1
    if cards.upper() == "END" :
        game_state = 1
        break
    else : 
        print (f"{cards}, is not a valid value, please enter a valid value!")

print ("Your score this round was " + str(round_total))
return round_total
```

When testing it doesn't seem to go through the prior logic checks before it comes to the conclusion that its an invalid value. NOTE this entire function was working as intended and does if i remove the else: statement at the end.  Is there anything in python similar to a case statement in java that would work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Replace all your if's (except the first one) with elif

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With multiple `if` statements at the same level, python will check each conditional statement. If you want it to ignore subsequent statements when a prior one has been satisfied, use `elif`:

```
def counting_up(game_state, game_level, round_total=0):
    """Request and add input card face value to score repeatedly till end."""
    while True:
        cards = input("Enter Card: \n")
        if cards.upper() == "END":
            game_state = 1; break
        elif cards == "0": 
            game_level += 1
        elif cards.upper() in ("A", "2"):
            round_total += 20
        elif cards.isnumeric():
            round_total += int(cards)
        elif cards.upper() in ("J","Q","K"):
            round_total += 10
        else: 
            print(f"{cards}, is not a valid value, please enter a valid value!")

    print(f"Your score this round was {round_total}.")
    return round_total
```

Comment: ah thank you, i was unsure if they should of been else if statements anyway to be honest, but it worked as intended so i decided to leave it as is.  Your explanation is a great help thank  you.

Answer (score 2):

Only the first 'if' should be an 'if' the rest of the 'if' statements should be replaced by 'elif' (else if) statements.

Answer (score 2):

"else" always checks the most recent "if" and then evaluates. So if you only enter "END" without having the break statement, the program won't go to the else statement. So anything you enter, other than "END", prints the result along with the result of the else statement.

Hence use "elif" for the statements other than the first "if" statement so that it checks the condition. If satisfied, prints the result else it moves on to the next statement

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dict`

```
def counting_up ():
    round_total = 0
    while True :
        global game_level
        cards = input("Enter Card: \n")
        card_dict = {'A':20,'2':20,'3':3,'4':4,'5':5,'6':6,'7':7,'8':8,'9':9,'10':10,'J':10,'Q':10,'K':10}
        if cards.upper() in card_dict.keys():
            round_total += card_dict[cards.upper()]
        elif cards == "0" : 
            game_level += 1
        elif cards.upper() == "END" :
            game_state = 1
            break
        else : 
            print (f"{cards}, is not a valid value, please enter a valid value!")

    print("Your score this round was " + str(round_total))
    return round_total
```

Comment: You want `if cards.upper()` in card_dict`  (O(1) lookup, where `in card_dict.keys()` is O(n) and also adds the overhead of building the `keys` view or list).

Comment: i was wondering initially if this could be done with something like lists, but couldn't grasp my head around it as initially i wanted the cards to display (planning on upgrading to an android app, once im fully happy with the code) I dont know much about dicts currently, but it seems to be alot easier when implementing something like this.   Ill keep this in mind Thank You